# Iterating over a layer and make MBR for every feature with QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents

I have a layer with about 20000 polygons in it. The `make extent layer` command just draws the MBR (Minimum Bounding Box) for the whole layer. I want to make MBR for each of them separately. Is there any way to iterate over the layer and make MBR for each of them?

Comment: What is MBR in this context?

Comment: it is Minimum Bounding Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the "bounding boxes" tool from the Processing toolbox. This gives one bounding box per feature.

Answer (score 1):

You go to Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers you can then try the following query :

```
select poly.id, st_envelope(poly.geometry) from poly
```

You can then **load the result as a new layer**.

*Adapt the query to meet your expectations according to your table structure...*

Comment: should i use my own layer name instead of "poly" ?

Comment: Yes sure and then you have to choose the attributes u want ("id" is an example but "geometry" is required)